# SAS Enterprise - ODS Output (file path error)

Tags: file, path, sas, authorization, filepath

I am trying to create an rts / pdf / whatever within SAS.

When I am trying to execute my program, the following message appears:

```
ods rtf file="output.rtf";” = ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access /data/sas/config/Lev1/gmaauswertungen/output.rtf.

ods rtf file="/H:/output.rtf"; = ERROR: Physical file does not exist, /H:/output.rtf.

ods rtf file="H:/output.rtf"; = ERROR: Physical file does not exist, /data/sas/config/Lev1/gmaauswertungen/H:/output.rtf.
```

I do not have local administrator rights - google was no help for me.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Rgds
Georg

Comment: Are you using SAS University Edition?

Comment: Hi - no, its the standard edition i guess. SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1

Comment: Where are these paths located? You're running EG against a windows or Linux server?  Can you access the path from the command line of the server the way you typed it?

Comment: I am on a windows Server (2012 R2) and running EG 7.1. In my case (and I suspect yours if your running on a Windows server), I just out-put the file (ODS) on the server, and write a PowerShell script to move the file into a local location. If someone has an easier way I would love to explore some new options...